# Meteor - Update packages in production

Tags: meteor, meteorite

How can I update my packages on production ? "mrt update before ./meteor.sh deploy" makes any difference on the bundle send to the server ?

I'm using meteor.sh to deploy and don't know if is there any update on the packages before goes into production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it correctly. When you create a bundle, it outputs a `.tgz` file containing **all** of the required dependencies. Therefore, in order to update any of the dependencies on the production server you need to re-bundle after updating.

You can prove this to yourself by comparing the file size and content of two bundles which only differ by a single `mrt update`.